# pass parameter in click function within id attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="div1" class="divs">some content</div>
<div id="div2" class="divs">some content</div>
<div id="div3" class="divs">some content</div>
<div id="div4" class="divs">some content</div>
<div id="div5" class="divs">some content</div>
<div id="div6" class="divs">some content</div>
```

and they all get a simple `.click()` function:

```
$divs = $('.divs');
$divs.click(function() {
  // some actions
}
```

what I would like to do is pass a parameter in the `.click()` function which gives me the current number of each `id` e.g. integer 1 for `id="div1`. Something like:

```
 $divs.click(function(e) {
  // e would be the number of the id inside the function
}
```

How could I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(this).index()+1`:

```
$divs.click(function() {
   alert($(this).index()+1);
});
```

Comment: and parameter 'e' can be omitted

Comment: okay that works, but could you please explain how this works and what exactly happens there?

Comment: @supersize: looking at the DOM you share, elements have id getting incremented in by 1. `.index()` returns the current index(0 based) of element. So adding one to fetched index solves the problem.

Comment: does this affect any other HTML, because my markup isn't just the `.divs`, furthermore I have `#div_1_1`, `#div_1_2` and so on.

Comment: @supersize: what do you mean by that. can you share the. as long as you are only targetting above DOM, it should work.

Comment: @supersize: This isn't how you'd accomplish this task. If you want to get the numbers from the ID, just extract them from the `.id` string.

Comment: @cookiemonster: ohh really...tell me a smarter way to do this.

Comment: Yes really. Your solution relies on them being siblings with no previous elements. It's hardly what anyone would do in a real world situation. Also it requires much more overhead. A much smarter way is to extract the information needed from `this.id`. If he wants `1_1`, then there are many ways to do it, like `this.id.slice(this.id.indexOf("_") + 1)`, with a conditional constraint if OP is unsure if the `.id` will have the desired data.

Comment: @cookiemonster: that is the reason i followed this approach.

Comment: That makes no sense. It's slow and fragile.

Comment: @cookiemonster there might be better solutions, but I gave this post my accept since I have average knowledge regarding some JS things. And regex is one of them, I simply understand what happens on Milinds answer, and that is what matters for me! When I don't understand it, it doesn't help me!

Comment: @supersize That's the reason why you need to ask, when you don't ask, people assume that you've already understand what happen, just like how you study in school?

Comment: @supersize: And that's why I downvoted it. People rely on getting good information. This doesn't qualify.

Comment: @cookiemonster: huhh. you have different defination of qualify then....you can see that by looking at upvotes.

Comment: @Felix sure, I will have an eye on it next time to make it clear what I don't get, I simply didn't want to be cheeky that you explain me regular expressions!

Comment: @MilindAnantwar: Upvotes on this site are meaningless. No knowledgeable developer would do this. You seem to post a lot of bad answers that get upvotes. I wouldn't be surprised if voter fraud was happening here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** with a simple regex to get the id number here:

```
$('.divs').click(function() {
    var id = this.id.match(/\d+$/);
    console.log(id);    
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dsGD9/)**

Comment: +1, but `.prop()` is unnecessary. `this.id` requires much less overhead. Also remember that `.match` returns an Array.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about IDs being unique. I'm just saying that `id` is going to hold an Array that holds the number at index `0` instead of the number itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$('.divs').click(function()
{
  var id = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/);
  alert(id);
});
```

Comment: but then I have to split the number from the string, does seem to complicate!

Comment: I have updated my answer. I missed the part about extracting the number from the string... still on the first cup of coffee.